# Is there a way to make a variable width font behave like a fixed width font in TLF?

Tags: apache-flex, tlf

Is there a way to make a variable width font behave like a fixed width font in TLF?

Example of variable width:
The quick grey fox jumped over the lazy dog.

Example of fixed width:

```
The quick grey fox jumped over the lazy dog
```

Notice how close the characters are to each other in the word "quick" and "grey" in each example.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to achieve?

[image]

(Upper font is Verdana and lower Tahoma)

The only way I see is to put every character into separate `SpanElement` when inserting (override `insertText` method of `EditManager` class), check it's AtomBounds on `UpdateCompleteEvent` and apply tracking or padding to the SpanElement depending on widths of these bounds.

EDIT: I just had a problem and tracking property saved me. This somehow reminded me this question, where I used kerning, while I actually had the tracking in mind. equal tracking for all atoms should do the trick.

Comment: No, just text broken apart in Flash and distributed evenly.